# IE 8 CSS display issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a [website here](http://www.jnarealestate.com/) that works terrific and displays fine in IE 10 and IE 11 but anything below that takes the whole display and forces it to the far left of the screen instead of centering the content area.  I can't seem to find where to adjust this in CSS. Can you please tell me a good way to fix this in IE 8 without "breaking" newer versions?

Comment: You have some rather serious markup issues. Fix these, and they'll likely bring you much closer to having a more consistent experience in legacy browsers: http://i.imgur.com/Q3pf3hP.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing that catches my eye is that the  should always be the very first line of your html.   If you move this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to the very top...   that should help with many of the errors.

You might also consider trying simply

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Since I don't have anything that still uses IE8 on it, I can't say for sure if that will fix everything, but it's a good start.   For what it's worth, I checked your site on Safari and Firefox, and it appears to work okay.   So I'm guessing IE8 has issues with the doctype not being in the correct spot.

One more thing...  there are three lines at the top of your page - title, and two meta tags.   Those belong inside the `<head>`, not at the top.